# CSS/JavaScript code works when implemented, but when I refresh the page it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, hidden

I am using the HTML widget for Elementor, a Wordpress theme builder. I am trying to show/hide sections (`sect1 - sect12` named *HTML*, *CSS*, *Javascript* and *Node*) when I click on certain buttons (`btn1, btn2, btn3`, named *Frontend Developer*, *Backend Developer* and *Designer*), and I got it to work, but when I refresh the page the buttons become unclickable. Each button controls 4 sections, so `btn1` -> `sect1 - sect4`, `btn2` -> `sect5 - sect8`, `btn3` -> `sect9 - sect 12`.

```
<script>
.elementor-editor-active .hidden{
  display:block;
}
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
.shown{
  display: block !important;
  animation: fade_in_anim 0.5s;
}
.btn_active_state{
  background-color: #D9D3FF !important;
}
@keyframes fade_in_anim {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll("[id^='btn']")]
const mapping = [[0, 4], [4, 8], [8,12]]
const sections = [...document.querySelectorAll("[id^='sect']")]

for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    toggleDivs(this)
    for(let j = mapping[i][0]; j < mapping[i][1]; j++) {
      sections[j].classList.add("shown", "fade")
    }
  })
}

function toggleDivs(btn){
  buttons.forEach(b => b.classList.remove("btn_active_state"))
  btn.classList.add("btn_active_state")
  sections.forEach(s => s.classList.remove('shown'))
}

//force button1 state initialise, if required
btn1.focus();
btn1.click();
</script>
<style>
.elementor-editor-active .hidden{
  display:block;
}
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
.shown{
  display: block !important;
  animation: fade_in_anim 0.5s;
}
.btn_active_state{
  background-color: #D9D3FF !important;
}
@keyframes fade_in_anim {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make an accordion menu?

You can show-hide with trigger

Comment: Yes, basically, but in Elementor I cannot select the number of columns I want my accordion to stretch on. In my case, I want an accordion which has 2 'menus' on the first column and 1 menu on the second column

Comment: Can you draw the exact structure you want and send it?
simsekm@msn.com

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant to my question. My structure worked, but only when I implemented it the first time. When I refresh the page it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I would do it and give it to you

Comment: I posted my code. I will also attach an image of the structure as I have made it on my website. The text fields are just placeholders for what I'm going to write later. I also edited the question description for better clarification